# Unable to get One ID and Another same name ID in one row?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am unable to get the coach into athlete names in one row

```
SELECT dev_test_team.team_id, dev_test_team.team_name,
dev_test_team.user_id, `dev_user`.`user_id` as `athlete_id`, 
`dev_user`.`user_type` FROM `dev_test_team`
CROSS JOIN `dev_user`
INNER JOIN `dev_test_teams_athlete` as `tt` ON `dev_user`.`user_id` = `tt`.`user_id` GROUP BY dev_test_team.team_id, dev_test_team.team_name, dev_test_team.user_id
```

this is the result when using **Cross join**  keyword with query

My dev_test_team table is:

[image]

My dev_test_teams_athlete table is:

[image]

My dev_user table is:

[image]

Finally, I want result like that as table shown

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |first_name(coach_name)| first_name(athlete_name) | team_id  | team_name
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        coach1                  athlete1                 1        ind
        coach2                  athlete2                 2        usa
        coach3                  athlete3                 3        uk
        coach3                  athlete4                 3        uk
```

Comment: The `2nd question` seems more like a demand and it is not obvious what the first question actually is!

Comment: sir, this 2dn question is first i will edit soon currently edit option not showing

Comment: i have edit my question RamRaider

Comment: Could you post data format instead of image because image is very hard to use.

Comment: sir, currently i am unable to available in data format sorry

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to `JOIN` on `dev_user` table twice.

one for `dev_test_teams_athlete` table.

another one for `dev_test_team` table.

```
CREATE TABLE dev_test_team(
   team_id int,
   team_name varchar(50),
   user_id int
);

insert into dev_test_team values (1,'indi',480);
insert into dev_test_team values (2,'usa', 472);
insert into dev_test_team values (3,'uk',  765);

CREATE TABLE dev_test_teams_athlete(
   teams_athlete_id int,
   team_id int,
   user_id int
);

insert into dev_test_teams_athlete values (12,1,380);
insert into dev_test_teams_athlete values (23,2,379);
insert into dev_test_teams_athlete values (24,3,479);
insert into dev_test_teams_athlete values (25,3,464);

CREATE TABLE dev_user(
   user_id int,
   first_name varchar(50)
);
insert into dev_user values (480,'coach1');
insert into dev_user values (472,'coach2');
insert into dev_user values (765,'coach3');
insert into dev_user values (380,'athlete1');
insert into dev_user values (379,'athlete2');
insert into dev_user values (479,'athlete3');
insert into dev_user values (464,'athlete4');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT coach.first_name 'first_name(coach_name)',
       athlete.first_name 'first_name(athlete_name)',
       dtt.team_id,
       dtt.team_name
FROM dev_test_team dtt 
INNER JOIN dev_test_teams_athlete  dtta on dtt.team_id = dtta.team_id
LEFT JOIN dev_user coach on dtt.user_id = coach.user_id
LEFT JOIN dev_user athlete on dtta.user_id = athlete.user_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5963b1/4/0)**:

```
| first_name(coach_name) | first_name(athlete_name) | team_id | team_name |
|------------------------|--------------------------|---------|-----------|
|                 coach1 |                 athlete1 |       1 |      indi |
|                 coach2 |                 athlete2 |       2 |       usa |
|                 coach3 |                 athlete3 |       3 |        uk |
|                 coach3 |                 athlete4 |       3 |        uk |
```

Comment: great sir, i am so happy with your answer this is acceptable answer

Comment: @Developertech. No problem glad to help